# Pivoting two colums leaving other columns in a table unchanged

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2012

I'd like to know if the following could be done in SQL Server 2012.

I have the following data:

```
Product_ID    Date     Attribute    Value
-------------------------------------------
10025135       2009    Colour       Red
10025135       2009    Size         20 cm
10025135       2009    Material     Steel
10025135       2010    Colour       Green
10025135       2010    Size         NULL
10025135       2010    Material     Alloy
10025136       2009    Colour       Black
10025136       2009    Size         30cm
10025136       2009    Material     NULL
```

I want to retrieve the data so that they are displayed as follows:

```
Product_ID    Date    Colour    Size     Material
-------------------------------------------------
10025135       2009   Red       20 cm    Steel
10025135       2010   Green     NULL     Alloy
10025136       2009   Black     30 cm    NULL
```

I've tried to pivot them without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT   Product_ID, Date, Colour, Size, Material
FROM
        (
            SELECT  Product_ID, Date, Attribute, Value
            FROM    Table1
        ) org
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX(Value)
            FOR Attribute IN (Colour, Size, Material)
        ) pivotHeader
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a857f/5)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════╦══════╦════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ PRODUCT_ID ║ DATE ║ COLOUR ║  SIZE  ║ MATERIAL ║
╠════════════╬══════╬════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║   10025135 ║ 2009 ║ Red    ║ 20 cm  ║ Steel    ║
║   10025135 ║ 2010 ║ Green  ║ (null) ║ Alloy    ║
║   10025136 ║ 2009 ║ Black  ║ 30cm   ║ (null)   ║
╚════════════╩══════╩════════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

The other way of doing this is by using `MAX()` and `CASE`

```
SELECT  Product_ID, DATE,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Colour' THEN Value END ) Colour,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Size' THEN Value END ) Size,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Material' THEN Value END ) Material
FROM    Table1
GROUP   BY Product_ID, DATE
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a857f/8)

Comment: How did you generate that sweet looking output table?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the using the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the desired result.  This will take the row values in the `attribute` column and convert them to columns.

The main thing to consider when doing this is whether you will have a known or unknown number of `attribute` values.

If the values are known ahead of time, then you can hard-code the values using a static `PIVOT`:

```
select product_id,
  Colour,
  Size,
  Material
from 
(
  select product_id, date, attribute, value
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for attribute in (Colour, Size, Material)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09358/1).

But if the values of the `attribute` column are unknown or will need to be dynamic, then you will need to implement dynamic SQL.  The dynamic SQL will get the list of columns to be used in a SQL string.

The code to get the list of columns would be similar to this:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(attribute) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

The result of this query is:

```
[Colour],[Material],[Size]
```

This creates on execution the list of `attributes` that should be converted to columns and it will be concatenated into the final string that is executed.  You code for the dynamic SQL pivot is:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(attribute) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT product_id,' + @cols + ' 
             from 
             (
                select product_id, date, attribute, value
                from yourtable
             ) x
             pivot 
             (
                max(value)
                for attribute in (' + @cols + ')
             ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19587/5).

The result for both queries is:

```
| PRODUCT_ID | COLOUR |   SIZE | MATERIAL |
-------------------------------------------
|   10025135 |    Red |  20 cm |    Steel |
|   10025136 |  Black |   30cm |   (null) |
|   10025135 |  Green | (null) |    Alloy |
```